# Summary text ("Q&A for...") corrupted for some sites in site-wide profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, network-profile, site-description

Look at the entries for The Workplace and Biblical Hermeneutics here:

[image: screen cap from accounts page]

What's special about these two that, alone among the sites where I have accounts, their entries just say "Q&A for" without the rest of the description?  The descriptions were there yesterday, possibly earlier today.

Edit: "View source" in my browser does not show the missing text, so this isn't a client-side rendering problem.  It happens in two different browsers, one where I'm logged in and one where I'm not.

Comment: It shows the description just fine for me... [All of them.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tAIfj.jpg)

Comment: Weird.  I just checked another browser and I'm seeing the same thing as in the screen shot.  So it's not just weird browser state, and hard-refreshing doesn't change it.  Firefox 17.0.1 and Safari 5.1.7, OS 10.6, though I wouldn't expect it to be a client-side problem.  The text that ought to be there is missing from page source.

Comment: Hmmm. It shows fine in all of my browsers. Does the description for The Workplace not show in [my profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/89201/animuson?tab=accounts) as well?

Comment: I'm definitely also seeing "Q&A for" at http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic

Comment: @animuson, the text is missing in your profile for The Workplace, Movies and TV, Computer Science, Sports, and Patents, but is present for the rest.  I don't know what the affected sites have in common.  Some of those I've never visited, for what that's worth.

Comment: @animuson doesn't show for me there either

Comment: @BenBrocka: Weird, every single site in that list shows a description for me. :/

Comment: I'm assuming that SE uses a bunch of web servers and some sort of load balancer; maybe there's one server/DB replica out there with the missing data and whether you see it depends on whether you hit that one?  (I know nothing about SE architecture so I'm totally speculating here...)

Comment: When I change the sorting to oldest, I see it too. It may be I didn't scroll far enough though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is now fixed.  One of the 5 web servers in our current datacenter had some bad cache caused by cosmic rays relayed by tidal forces from the moons of Saturn....or something.

Comment: Not Mayans with a Julian-shift thing going on, then? :-)