# Stack Exchange sites list displaying some beta sites wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, information-display, beta-sites

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Summary text (“Q&A for…”) corrupted for some sites in site-wide profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161107/summary-text-qa-for-corrupted-for-some-sites-in-site-wide-profile)

At https://stackexchange.com/sites#name, I see:

[image: sample 0]

[image: sample 1]

The messed-up sites are missing their "Q&A for" description, and show up as created some time during the early Roman Empire.

However, not all beta sites are messed up:

[image: Working beta sites]

For this one, I admit the time is approximately accurate:

[image: Jesus fish]